# Java 8: Sonar compliant Server Socket

Tags: java, sockets, sonarqube-scan

Below is my `run()` of my Server Socket Thread which will be running as `Executors.newWorkStealingPool().submit(() -> mainServer.run());` and accepts client connections. It runs fine but `Sonar` is complaining it as `Bug` of Type `Loops should not be infinite (squid:S2189)`

```
    class MainServer {
    private final ServerSocket serverSocket;    
    private final boolean checkClientCerts;
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainServer.class.getName());
    private final int threadPoolSize;
    private boolean running;
    private ExecutorService executorService;    

 MainServer(int port, boolean checkClientCerts, int threadPoolSize, InetAddress bindAddress) throws IOException {

        LOG.debug("Locating server socket factory for SSL...");
        SSLServerSocketFactory factory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        LOG.debug("Creating a server socket on port " + port);
        SSLServerSocket serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket) factory.createServerSocket(port, 0, bindAddress);        
        this.checkClientCerts = checkClientCerts;
        this.threadPoolSize = threadPoolSize;
    }

    void run() {
        running = true;
        DefaultThreadFactory threadFactory = new DefaultThreadFactory("SSLHandshake");
        executorService = new ShutdownThreadPoolExecutor(threadPoolSize,threadFactory);

        while (running) {
            Socket clientSocket;

            try {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                MainServerHandshakeThread handshakeThread = new MainServerHandshakeThread(clientSocket, this);                
                executorService.submit(handshakeThread);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                LOG.error("Error accepting connection",ex);
            }

        }
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        LOG.info("Stopping main server...");
        running = false;
        try {
            if (serverSocket!=null) {
                serverSocket.close();
            }
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            LOG.debug("Failed to close socket",ex);
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            if (!executorService.awaitTermination(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                executorService.shutdownNow();
            } 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            executorService.shutdownNow();
        }             
        LOG.info("Main server stopped...");
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me how to optimize above block of code to get rid of Sonar complaint?

Comment: Well, why not apply what the warning says and make the `while (running) {...}` loop **not** infinite? You never change the `running` variable in the code that you shared.

Comment: @Fureeish updated the question with complete code, `mainServer` will be running as `Executors.newWorkStealingPool().submit(() -> mainServer.run());` and it will be stopped by invoking `shutdown()` when the application is stopped

Comment: Does marking `running` as `volatile` get rid of the bug?

Comment: @Fureeish Yes, surprisingly marking `running` as `volatile` get rid of the bug, whats the magic behind it?

Comment: Please see my answer, I tried to both briefly explain what's happening and to provide some additional reads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark your `running` as `volatile`.

`volatile` marks a variable <s>visible to</s> as changeable<sup>1</sup> by *other threads*. That means that an optimiser (or a code-analyzer, like SonarQube) *cannot* assume that other threads *do not* modify such variable. In your example, both of those could assume that `running` **never changes**, thus marking your code as having an infinite loop. A similar example can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/106787/7151494).

You should mark your variables as `volatile`, if they can be accessed and modified by other threads.

---

<sup>1</sup> Corrected by **user207421**.

Comment: It is already visible to other threads. `volatile` means it can be *changed* by other threads.